# Unicode exception class

Tags: c++, exception, unicode

I want to implement header-only class with unicode exception and I've started with the following code:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class uexception : public exception
{
public:
    explicit uexception(const wchar_t* msg)
    {
         this->msg = msg;
    }

    explicit uexception(const wstring& msg)
    {
         this->msg = msg;
    }

    const wchar_t* uwhat() const throw ()
    {
        return msg.c_str();
    }

private:
    wstring msg;

    const char* what() const throw () //hidden
    { 
        return NULL;  
    } 
};
```

This works fine, but I have some questions:

1. Why do I need to derive from std::exception class? May be this not needed at all?
2. Am I miss something in my class implementation?

Comment: A slight warning (and related to your second question): On Windows the `wchar_t` is only 16 bits. Use plain `char` if your internal encoding is UTF-8, or `char32_t` if you use UTF-32 internally. See e.g. [this character type reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types%23Character_types#Character_types) for more information.

Comment: Regarding your first question: No, you don't *need* to derive from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception), but if you don't then programs which catches `std:exception` will not catch your exceptions, and need to add special cases just for your library. Oh and by the way, if you want to exchange the standard exceptions with your "Unicode aware" exceptions, don't forget to reimplement the whole existing exception hierarchy.

Comment: Lastly, is there really a *need* for this exception library? Many compilers will gladly accept UTF-8 string literals meaning you can already have Unicode in the normal standard exceptions.

Comment: Do not use exception specifications (ie: `throw()`), they are deprecated. Also, use `override` on your `what()` function, and optionally `virtual`. And `uwhat()` should be virtual, so that exceptions who derive `uexception` can possibly change how the message is returned. Returning `NULL` (or `nullptr`) from a function returning a `char *` is a bad idea: first because it should be `""`, and second because code catching `std::exception` won't get any error message

Comment: Don't use `using namespace std;` (in general) *especially not* in a header, since you'll polute the global namespace for everyone including your header - not a nice thing to do.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The standard `what()` message is decoded according to the platform's convention. Using UTF-8 in Windows would  be a way to at least occasionally scramble text beyond recognition. But it's highly recommended by those who port Unixland programs which can't even handle Windows paths (one of my most eye-opening experiences was with the Qt installer, once: it couldn't handle backspace, much like the baffling keyboard problems with all Unix editors I'd used up through the 1990's).

Comment: @JesperJuhl, good point, I will fix it by using std:: prefix for each variable

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't have to inherit `std::exception`. Inheriting it directly, or indirectly has the advantage of allowing users of your interface to catch your exception by reference to `std::exception` - without depending on the definition of your exception type.

   Of course, accessing `uwhat` won't be possible through `std::exception` anyway, so if you don't intend to implement my suggestion<sup>†</sup>, then not inheriting `std::exception` might even be desirable for your design.
2. If you do decide to inherit, then reducing the visibility of `what` is not possible. <sup>††</sup>

   Your implementation of `what` violates the interface of `std::exception` by not returning a pointer to a null terminated string. If an exception handler catches that by reference to `std::exception`, calls `what()` and dereferences the pointer, chaos will ensue.

   A trivial way to implement `what` would be to `return ""` instead. However... <sup>†</sup>

<sup>†</sup> I recommend considering an alternative: Instead of returning "nothing", you could convert the encoding of the stored wide string to the native narrow string enconding and return a pointer to that. Sure, that would be a lot more work to implement, but would also make your exception much more convenient.

<sup>††</sup> Technically you can reduce the visibility of `uexception::what`, as you have but it does not affect the visibility of `uexception::exception::what`. Besides, doing so violates Liskov substitution principle. I recommend that you either inherit `std::exception` and implement `what` publicly and properly, or don't inherit `std::exception` at all.

Comment: Reducing the visibility of `what()` is definitely a possibility, and might even be a good idea here: clients who catch the `uexception` through `std::exception` can still call `what()`, but those who catch `uexception` directly should call `uwhat()` instead.

Comment: @KABoissonneault technically yes. My intended meaning was more subtle. See the edit.